# Laravel and bootstrap glyphicons - where are files copied, how to set relative path and how to solve cachebusting?

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

Im having trouble understanding how to use glyphicons with laravel 5.4.

I have the following questions:

1) When i run "npm run dev" glyphicon files are copied to public/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap. Where does this happen and can i change the path? I don't have not explicitly configured this in my webpack:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

2) If i want to link previously mentioned glyphicons in my css i add the following line to my _variables.scss:

```
$icon-font-path: "/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/";
```

But the problem is that my browser cant find the resources:

```
GET https://localhost/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED
```

And that i because the resources are really located at:

```
https://localhost/MYAPP/PUBLIC/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

How can i make the path in my scss relative?

3) When i moved glypicon files to localhost/fonts just to test it out it worked. But after i added cachebusting to webpack it stopped working again.

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .version();
```

... and this happens because in css glypgicon files are also versioned:

```
src: url(/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1);
```

But in reality it is not versioned. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 3):

By default Mix [will rewrite and optimize any url() calls within your stylesheets](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#url-processing). That results in your final CSS having `url(/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/...)`, but that url is absolute, so the `fonts` directory is expected at the root of your webserver.

- As a first option, it would be best to configure your webserver to serve the `public` directory as document root. This is a webserver-specific configuration (Apache, nginx...). Or, even better, Valet if it's available to you (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/valet for Mac, https://github.com/cpriego/valet-linux for Linux).
- Alternatively, set the resource root path at your app public folder:

  ```
  mix.setResourceRoot('/MYAPP/public/')
  ```
- Finally, you could just have the fonts files in your `public/fonts` directory:

  ```
  $icon-font-path: "../fonts/bootstrap/";
  ```

  and

  ```
  mix.options({ processCssUrls: false })
    .copy('node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts', 'public/fonts')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Since your application is within a directory to directory (https://localhost/MYAPP/PUBLIC/). You may remove the slash on your `_variables.scss` so instead:

```
$icon-font-path: "/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/";
```

you may try this:

```
$icon-font-path: "fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/";
```

You may edit your VirtualHost of your application pointing to the `public` directory and add the URL to your `hosts` file.

You may also try to use [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com) is faster than `npm`

Comment: Tried to remove slash but then npm run dev wont work because i get:

These relative modules were not found:

* ./fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrapglyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 in ./~/css-loader?{"url":true,"sourceMap":false}!./~/postcss-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"precision":8,"outputStyle":"expanded","sour
ceMap":true}!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss